# cl.exe using default para

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have the  `vs2012 pro` and my `cl.exe` is in this path `“E:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin”`

`test.cpp` is a `“hello world”` program

I run the `vcvars32.bat` and then type F:\gts>cl test.cpp：

```
F:\gts>cl test.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'E:\Microsoft', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Visual', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Studio', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '11.0\VC\bin', object file assumed
test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

then the `link.exe` talk me：

```
/out:Microsoft.exe
E:\Microsoft
Visual
Studio
11.0\VC\bin
test.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'E:\Microsoft.obj'
```

So I can get the *.obj but cannt get the *.exe

I think the cl.exe take the path `“E:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin”` as the first para，but I dont konw the reason

p.s. when I using the vs2012, everthing is right.